# Ignore OCaml interfaces with OCamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have a large library and I would like to create a target that packs all of the modules but ignores the `.mli` files that are present in the source directory. Is there a simple way of using `ocamlbuild` via a plugin or special set of `_tags` that could easily accomplish this.

One potential solution, that I can think of is new `OCaml` compilation rules in the plugin and set them to have higher precedence than the build in rules.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `ocamlbuild` will first try to use `mli` to compile `cmi` file of it. If it can't find the `mli` file, then it will invalidate this rule and try the next one. The `ocamlbuild -documentation` command will show precisely the order of rules. If more than one rule applies, then the first one is chosen. Unfortunately there is no interface to change the order of rules, or to delete a rule (other than deleting all rules). But we can add our own rule to the top of the list, that will override the offending rule. For this we need to write the following `myocamlbuild.ml` plugin:

```
open Ocamlbuild_plugin
module Compiler = Ocamlbuild_pack.Ocaml_compiler

let override () = 
  rule "ocaml-override: ml -> cmo & cmi"
    ~insert:`top
    ~prods:["%.cmo"; "%.cmi"]
    ~deps:["%.ml"; "%.ml.depends"]
    ~doc:"This rule disables mli files."
    (Compiler.byte_compile_ocaml_implem "%.ml" "%.cmo")   

let () = dispatch (function
    | After_rules -> override ()
    | _ -> ())
```

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. By directory I mean source directory. I think that you know that `.mli` files impose an interface on modules defined in regular `.ml` files. They are not a requirement in `OCaml` and you can easily infer the signature (ie. `.mli`) from a `.ml`. I want to use `ocamlbuild` to compile my project ignoring my currently imposed interface.

Comment: kind of strange requirement, not surprising that I didn't get it :) So, yes it is possible to do it with `ocamlbuild`. I will update the answer with explanations.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I had tried something similar, but only now realized the need to list "%.ml.depends" as a dependency.